# subtract 2 DB rows from each other for each unique partner_ID? MYSQL

Tags: mysql, subtraction

I have a MYSQL table where I need to get to subtract values from 2 different rows.

This is my DB table:

Tablename: `ext_partnertotals`

```
| Partner_ID | Partnername | Month | Year | Total |
|------------|-------------|-------|------|-------|
| 1          | Partner 1   | 1     | 2018 | 10    |
| 1          | Partner 1   | 2     | 2018 | 12    |
| 2          | Partner 2   | 1     | 2018 | 18    |
| 2          | Partner 2   | 2     | 2018 | 12    |
```

It should get this with a query:

```
| Partner_ID | Partnername | up/down |
|------------|-------------|---------|
| 1          | Partner 1   | +2      |
| 2          | Partner 2   | -6      |
```

I need to get the Subtract value of 2 different months for each Partner.
Every Partner has a tablerow for each month and a value for that month.
Now I need to get If they went up or went down in value since the month before.
Can someone write me a query?

Comment: Please your query or table structure then only we can help

Comment: What is your desired behaviour when there's a gap in the data for a given partner (i.e. data for January and March but nothing for February): should the month (March) be compared against the last month for which data exists (January), or should it only ever be compared against the previous month (February—ergo no result or NULL when it doesn't exist)?

Comment: There will never be a gap, but I will be possible that a partner has no data for those 2 months and then it should not appear in the list. I'm using an older version, version 7.0 I think

Comment: Note also that the presence of `Partnername` in this table violates [1NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form)—you should consider moving that column to a separate table of partner data.  Furthermore, it would simplify things if `Month` and `Year` were combined into a single `DATE` type column.  Are such structural changes possible?  In any event, your resultset will need to include sufficient information to identify the month for which the movement is given.

Comment: I don't have any rights to change those things, my boss decided this.... Yes its not a smart choice but i have to deal with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're unable to improve your terrible schema, I recommend you use a (very ugly/hard to maintain and very slow) correlated subquery:

```
SELECT Partner_ID, Partnername, Year, Month, Total - (
  SELECT Total
  FROM   ext_partnertotals AS prev
  WHERE  prev.Partner_ID = cur.Partner_ID AND CASE cur.Month
           WHEN 1 THEN prev.Year = cur.Year - 1 AND prev.Month = 12
           ELSE prev.Year = cur.Year AND prev.Month = cur.Month - 1
         END
) AS `up/down` FROM ext_partnertotals AS cur
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8a9a923/1/0).

Comment: Thanks I edited your answer and It worked, so your answer helped me a lot! thanks!